# Getting Shaded relief from DXF mesh using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, dxf, shaded-relief, mesh

I am stuck with a problem in QGIS. I have a three-dimensional mesh as DXF from AutoCAD, which I imported into QGIS.

Now I wanted to create a shaded relief map. I think I need to create a raster from the mesh first. I tried converting the mesh to lines and the rasterize these lines, but this approach didn´t seem to work.

Has anyone any suggestions?

Comment: I think you are interested in the vertexs of your mesh rather than the lines. From your vertexs you can try any of the interpolation tools to produce a raster dtm

Comment: I have not used it, but have a look to https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_interpolation.html?highlight=interpolation

Comment: Thanks @Marco, this has solved my issue - I imported my mesh as XYZ pointcloud and used Interpolation to generate a TIN.